# AEM 6.3 Customize log message using appender and slf4j

Tags: logging, aem

In our AEM 6.3 project, we have a need to add the additional attribute in log message. Basically, we want to customize the message format. So we have created one logback file under src/main/resources/logback.xml. Content of the logfile is as follows

```
<configuration>

<appender name="SampleProject.log" 
class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>SampleProject.log</file>
     <append>true</append>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d %-5level %X{sling.userId:-NA} [%thread] %logger{30} 
    %marker- %msg %n</pattern>
        <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush>
    </encoder>
  </appender>

 <logger name="org.wc.project" level="INFO"/>

 </configuration>
```

And under Apache Sling Logging Configuration, we have created one log configuration as follows with "same name" as appender name.

```
org.apache.sling.commons.log.file="SampleProject.log"
org.apache.sling.commons.log.level="info"
org.apache.sling.commons.log.logger.paatern ="org.wc.project"
org.apache.sling.commons.log.pattern="{0,date,dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS} 
*{4}* [{2}] {3} {5}"
```

But the customized message format is now shown in SampleProject.log. Can anybody please provide any pointers for the same.

Comment: Any clue on the above issue?

Answer (score 0):

Realize this is a pretty old thread at this point, but I have accomplished something similar in the past through writing a MDC Filter for sling, and having the filter updated using MDC logging patterns.

I wrote a step-by-step write-up on how to accomplish this here:

https://blogs.perficientdigital.com/2018/09/24/customized-logging-using-slf4j-mdc-in-aem/

***Edit:*** Copy/Pasting the basic steps from the url above in case it's no longer accessible:

To utilize MDC, there are two main steps:
 - Populating the MDC Object (Map)
 - Referencing the MDC Properties (Logging Pattern)

In AEM, every request flows through a filter chain, meaning we need to populate the MDC variable early enough in the filter that we can successfully log those variables later.  The easiest way to do this is to set the scope of a custom filter to be at the request level, order 0:

```
/**
 - The SlingFilterScope.REQUEST is important as MDC needs to be configured prior
 - to any logger being executed in the page rendering.
 */
@SlingFilter(
        label = "Sample MDC Filter",
        description = "Sample implementation of custom MDC properties.",
        order = 0,
        scope = SlingFilterScope.REQUEST)
```

Then you need to import the org.slf4j.MDC into your class and populate it.

```
MDC.put(varName,varValue);
```

Once you've populated the variable, you can access it via the standard logging filters:

```
%X{varName:-DefaultValueIfNull}
```

The rest of the logic is up to you!  The request object gives you direct access to the following:

- ResourceResolver (Access to JCR)
- Request Headers
- You can use a RequestWrapper to customize
- Request Cookies
- Request Parameters